# Writing dbf file in C#(.net6) from Scratch

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-foxpro

i want to save DataTable as dbf file but i don't know how to do that...
i googled it but result was old and didn't work in .net 6.
can anybody guide how do that please?

Comment: Check this questions, might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322792/how-can-i-save-a-datatable-to-a-dbf

Comment: `DBF` is old, so all relevant answers are also old. Like 1990s old. `DBF` was the format of dBase IV and later Clipper. FoxPro could also work with it. So does MS Access.  You'll have to use an ADO.NET or ODBC driver for such files. Access itself installs an ODBC driver for DBF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use EF then you can check Tom Brother's VFP EF provider:

[EF Core Provider VFP](https://github.com/tombrothers/EntityFrameworkCore.Vfp)

I prefer to directly use ADO.Net with VFPOLEDB provider. You need to make sure you are compiling for 32 bits.

Comment: _"You need to make sure you are compiling for 32 bits."_ - this isn't an option on many modern platforms though.

Comment: @Dai, if you would use VFPOLEDB provider it is a must. You can try ADS from Sybase but as far as I know it is not for free.